# mvtnorm fails to load in MS r-client version 3.4.3

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-r

When trying to load the library seriation in **MS R-Client** in Windows, I get the following message:

The library seriation fails to load with the following message:

> library(seriation) # package for reordering a distance matrix
>   *Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘seriation’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):* 
>   there is no package called ‘mvtnorm’ In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘seriation’ was built under R version 3.4.4

The current version of mvtnorm, 1.0-9 requires r version 3.5 or greater.  I have tried installing the package from source from several versions as well as several versions from source here:  https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvtnorm/

The error message from these attempts is:

- > installing *source* package 'mvtnorm' ...
  >   ** package 'mvtnorm' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  >   ** libs Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/RCLIEN~1/R_SERVER/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f
  >   "C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/RCLIEN~1/R_SERVER/share/make/winshlib.mk"
  >   SHLIB="mvtnorm.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FLIBS)' WIN=64 TCLBIN=64
  >   OBJECTS="C_FORTRAN_interface.o miwa.o mvt.o mvtnorm-init.o tvpack.o"'
  >   had status 127 ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mvtnorm'
- > removing 'D:/Users/KNel/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/mvtnorm' In R CMD
  >   INSTALL Warning messages: 1: running command
  >   '"C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/RCLIEN~1/R_SERVER/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
  >   "D:\Users\KNel\Documents\R\win-library\3.4"
  >   "C:/Users/KNel/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQRtAJK/downloaded_packages/mvtnorm_1.0-6.tar.gz"'
  >   had status 1  2: In utils::install.packages(...) :   installation of
  >   package
  >   ‘C:/Users/KNel/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQRtAJK/downloaded_packages/mvtnorm_1.0-6.tar.gz’
  >   had non-zero exit status

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mvtnorm` starting 1.0.9 requires R >= 3.5.0 (per package info  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html)

So if you're trying to install it for R 3.4.3, you'd need  `mvtnorm` version 1.0.8, which is available from CRAN archive:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvtnorm/mvtnorm_1.0-8.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

Ref: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mvtnorm/versions/1.0-8